# How does Yii2 Url::remember() work?

Tags: php, heroku, yii, yii2

How does [Url::remember()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#remember()-detail) work? I thought it stores the URL in a cookie, but I don't see it. It's working locally, but not on Heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to source code, it saves URL in session:

```
public static function remember($url = '', $name = null)
{
    $url = static::to($url);

    if ($name === null) {
        Yii::$app->getUser()->setReturnUrl($url);
    } else {
        Yii::$app->getSession()->set($name, $url);
    }
}
```

`setReturnUrl` will call:

```
Yii::$app->getSession()->set($this->returnUrlParam, $url);
```

**Official docs:**

- [Session set()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html#set%28%29-detail)
- [User setReturnUrl()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#setReturnUrl%28%29-detail)

Comment: Ok, but where does it save the session? I thought it was using cookie sessions, like Rails.

Comment: No.[Session component](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-session.html) is a wrapper of some native php session functions.